# Plugin not working with current jQuery, TypeError in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Using http://jsfiddle.net/heygrady/j5tHC/light/ as my example, trying to update to current jQuery, in my case 1.11.0

Works with jQuery 1.6.2, when I update to current version it throws an error in the console, "TypeError: f is undefined" I can't figure out why it makes a difference or track the variable, seems like it has the same values in both.

The following code runs the animation:

```
tween($.curve.bezier, {
            x: 0,
            y: $canvas[0].height,
            points: [
                [0, $canvas[0].height / 2],
                [$canvas[0].width * 0.5, 0],
                [$canvas[0].width * 0.9, $canvas[0].height],
                [$canvas[0].width, $canvas[0].height/ 2]
            ]
        });
```

I believe this is the function that is breaking inside the plugin:

```
(function (f, g, j, b) {
  var h = /progid:DXImageTransform\.Microsoft\.Matrix\(.*?\)/,
  c = /^([\+\-]=)?([\d+.\-]+)(.*)$/,
  q = /%/;
  var d = j.createElement('modernizr'),
  e = d.style;
  function n(s) {
    return parseFloat(s)
  }
  function l() {
    var s = {
      transformProperty: '',
      MozTransform: '-moz-',
      WebkitTransform: '-webkit-',
      OTransform: '-o-',
      msTransform: '-ms-'
    };
    for (var t in s) {
      if (typeof e[t] != 'undefined') {
        return s[t]
      }
    }
    return null
  }
  function r() {
    if (typeof (g.Modernizr) !== 'undefined') {
      return Modernizr.csstransforms
    }
    var t = [
      'transformProperty',
      'WebkitTransform',
      'MozTransform',
      'OTransform',
      'msTransform'
    ];
    for (var s in t) {
      if (e[t[s]] !== b) {
        return true
      }
    }
  }
  var a = l(),
  i = a !== null ? a + 'transform' : false,
  k = a !== null ? a + 'transform-origin' : false;
  f.support.csstransforms = r();
  if (a == '-ms-') {
    i = 'msTransform';
    k = 'msTransformOrigin'
  }
  f.extend({
    transform: function (s) {
      s.transform = this;
      this.$elem = f(s);
      this.applyingMatrix = false;
      this.matrix = null;
      this.height = null;
      this.width = null;
      this.outerHeight = null;
      this.outerWidth = null;
      this.boxSizingValue = null;
      this.boxSizingProperty = null;
      this.attr = null;
      this.transformProperty = i;
      this.transformOriginProperty = k
    }
  });
  f.extend(f.transform, {
    funcs: [
      'matrix',
      'origin',
      'reflect',
      'reflectX',
      'reflectXY',
      'reflectY',
      'rotate',
      'scale',
      'scaleX',
      'scaleY',
      'skew',
      'skewX',
      'skewY',
      'translate',
      'translateX',
      'translateY'
    ]
  });
  f.fn.transform = function (s, t) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var u = this.transform || new f.transform(this);
      if (s) {
        u.exec(s, t)
      }
    })
  };
  f.transform.prototype = {
    exec: function (s, t) {
      t = f.extend(true, {
        forceMatrix: false,
        preserve: false
      }, t);
      this.attr = null;
      if (t.preserve) {
        s = f.extend(true, this.getAttrs(true, true), s)
      } else {
        s = f.extend(true, {
        }, s)
      }
      this.setAttrs(s);
      if (f.support.csstransforms && !t.forceMatrix) {
        return this.execFuncs(s)
      } else {
        if (f.browser.msie || (f.support.csstransforms && t.forceMatrix)) {
          return this.execMatrix(s)
        }
      }
      return false
    },
    execFuncs: function (t) {
      var s = [
      ];
      for (var u in t) {
        if (u == 'origin') {
          this[u].apply(this, f.isArray(t[u]) ? t[u] : [
            t[u]
          ])
        } else {
          if (f.inArray(u, f.transform.funcs) !== - 1) {
            s.push(this.createTransformFunc(u, t[u]))
          }
        }
      }
      this.$elem.css(i, s.join(' '));
      return true
    },
    execMatrix: function (z) {
      var C,
      x,
      t;
      var F = this.$elem[0],
      B = this;
      function A(N, M) {
        if (q.test(N)) {
          return parseFloat(N) / 100 * B['safeOuter' + (M ? 'Height' : 'Width')]()
        }
        return o(F, N)
      }
      var s = /translate[X|Y]?/,
      u = [
      ];
      for (var v in z) {
        switch (f.type(z[v])) {
        case 'array':
          t = z[v];
          break;
        case 'string':
          t = f.map(z[v].split(','), f.trim);
          break;
        default:
          t = [
            z[v]
          ]
        }
        if (f.matrix[v]) {
          if (f.cssAngle[v]) {
            t = f.map(t, f.angle.toDegree)
          } else {
            if (!f.cssNumber[v]) {
              t = f.map(t, A)
            } else {
              t = f.map(t, n)
            }
          }
          x = f.matrix[v].apply(this, t);
          if (s.test(v)) {
            u.push(x)
          } else {
            C = C ? C.x(x)  : x
          }
        } else {
          if (v == 'origin') {
            this[v].apply(this, t)
          }
        }
      }
      C = C || f.matrix.identity();
      f.each(u, function (M, N) {
        C = C.x(N)
      });
      var K = parseFloat(C.e(1, 1) .toFixed(6)),
      I = parseFloat(C.e(2, 1) .toFixed(6)),
      H = parseFloat(C.e(1, 2) .toFixed(6)),
      G = parseFloat(C.e(2, 2) .toFixed(6)),
      L = C.rows === 3 ? parseFloat(C.e(1, 3) .toFixed(6))  : 0,
      J = C.rows === 3 ? parseFloat(C.e(2, 3) .toFixed(6))  : 0;
      if (f.support.csstransforms && a === '-moz-') {
        this.$elem.css(i, 'matrix(' + K + ', ' + I + ', ' + H + ', ' + G + ', ' + L + 'px, ' + J + 'px)')
      } else {
        if (f.support.csstransforms) {
          this.$elem.css(i, 'matrix(' + K + ', ' + I + ', ' + H + ', ' + G + ', ' + L + ', ' + J + ')')
        } else {
          if (f.browser.msie) {
            var w = ', FilterType=\'nearest neighbor\'';
            var D = this.$elem[0].style;
            var E = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=' + K + ', M12=' + H + ', M21=' + I + ', M22=' + G + ', sizingMethod=\'auto expand\'' + w + ')';
            var y = D.filter || f.curCSS(this.$elem[0], 'filter') || '';
            D.filter = h.test(y) ? y.replace(h, E)  : y ? y + ' ' + E : E;
            this.applyingMatrix = true;
            this.matrix = C;
            this.fixPosition(C, L, J);
            this.applyingMatrix = false;
            this.matrix = null
          }
        }
      }
      return true
    },
    origin: function (s, t) {
      if (f.support.csstransforms) {
        if (typeof t === 'undefined') {
          this.$elem.css(k, s)
        } else {
          this.$elem.css(k, s + ' ' + t)
        }
        return true
      }
      switch (s) {
      case 'left':
        s = '0';
        break;
      case 'right':
        s = '100%';
        break;
      case 'center':
      case b:
        s = '50%'
      }
      switch (t) {
      case 'top':
        t = '0';
        break;
      case 'bottom':
        t = '100%';
        break;
      case 'center':
      case b:
        t = '50%'
      }
      this.setAttr('origin', [
        q.test(s) ? s : o(this.$elem[0], s) + 'px',
        q.test(t) ? t : o(this.$elem[0], t) + 'px'
      ]);
      return true
    },
    createTransformFunc: function (t, u) {
      if (t.substr(0, 7) === 'reflect') {
        var s = u ? f.matrix[t]()  : f.matrix.identity();
        return 'matrix(' + s.e(1, 1) + ', ' + s.e(2, 1) + ', ' + s.e(1, 2) + ', ' + s.e(2, 2) + ', 0, 0)'
      }
      if (t == 'matrix') {
        if (a === '-moz-') {
          u[4] = u[4] ? u[4] + 'px' : 0;
          u[5] = u[5] ? u[5] + 'px' : 0
        }
      }
      return t + '(' + (f.isArray(u) ? u.join(', ')  : u) + ')'
    },
    fixPosition: function (B, y, x, D, s) {
      var w = new f.matrix.calc(B, this.safeOuterHeight(), this.safeOuterWidth()),
      C = this.getAttr('origin');
      var v = w.originOffset(new f.matrix.V2(q.test(C[0]) ? parseFloat(C[0]) / 100 * w.outerWidth : parseFloat(C[0]), q.test(C[1]) ? parseFloat(C[1]) / 100 * w.outerHeight : parseFloat(C[1])));
      var t = w.sides();
      var u = this.$elem.css('position');
      if (u == 'static') {
        u = 'relative'
      }
      var A = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      };
      var z = {
        position: u,
        top: (v.top + x + t.top + A.top) + 'px',
        left: (v.left + y + t.left + A.left) + 'px',
        zoom: 1
      };
      this.$elem.css(z)
    }
  };
  function o(s, u) {
    var t = c.exec(f.trim(u));
    if (t[3] && t[3] !== 'px') {
      var w = 'paddingBottom',
      v = f.style(s, w);
      f.style(s, w, u);
      u = p(s, w);
      f.style(s, w, v);
      return u
    }
    return parseFloat(u)
  }
  function p(t, u) {
    if (t[u] != null && (!t.style || t.style[u] == null)) {
      return t[u]
    }
    var s = parseFloat(f.css(t, u));
    return s && s > - 10000 ? s : 0
  }
}) (jQuery, this, this.document);
```

Comment: if so, your problem is in the plugin, not with jQuery. you should update your tags to reflect this.

Comment: When you updated you version of jQuery, did you add the new version in the same place the previous one was? The self-executing function takes jQuery as the first parameter - if f is undefined within the function then it infers jQuery is undefined at the point the function is executed. Make sure jQuery is added on the page **before** the plugin.

Comment: What is the plugin??

Comment: Don't believe it's a script placement issue as it happens with jsfiddle as well, just change the jquery version

Comment: **You have not asked a question in your OP**.  What exactly is your question?  The "transform" plugin _I think_ you're using has a big bold **NO LONGER MAINTAINED** message on its [GitHub page](https://github.com/heygrady/transform#no-longer-maintained).  It just may not be compatible with the latest version of jQuery.  [The "Curve" plugin](https://github.com/heygrady/curve) has not been touched since 2011 (jQuery 1.6.x).  This is what can happen when you use really old plugins with newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: My question is, how can I get it to work with a newer version of jQuery, or is there an alternative. I'm looking to animate an image along a bezier curve, rotating the image to follow the path of the curve as it travels.